# Python Programming MOOC 2021 - Students in groups

Tags: python

no consigo resolver este ejercicio en Python y no entiendo porqué.
Hay que dividir a los alumnos en grupos, si son alumnos pares todos los grupos serán del mismo tamaño, pero si son impares habrá un grupo extra con alumnos impares

Mi código:

```
numberStudents = int(input("How many students on the course?"))
groupSize = int(input("Desired group size?"))

division = numberStudents // groupSize

if division % 2 == 0:
    print("Number of groups formed:", division)

if division % 2 != 0:
    print("Number of groups formed:", str(division+1))
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está mal planteada la solución: los grupos que necesitas no depende si hay un número par de estudiantes. El número de grupos se obtiene analizando el resto de la división: si hay resto, quedan estudiantes para un último grupo incompleto.

```
numberStudents = int(input("How many students on the course?"))
groupSize = int(input("Desired group size?"))

division = numberStudents // groupSize
resto = numberStudents % groupSize
if resto == 0 :
    print("Number of groups formed:", division)
else:
    print("Number of groups formed:", division+1)
```

**Demo**

```
How many students on the course?36
Desired group size?6
Number of groups formed: 6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

otra:

```
How many students on the course?30
Desired group size?4
Number of groups formed: 8

Process finished with exit code 0
```